# A circular dependency was detected to table1[count],table1[sum],table1[count] in dax powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Below are the details of table1 where I've few columns like shop, shelf and product. It represents a particular shop has a particular shelf where products are being placed.

```
shop    shelf   product
a        a1     p1xxxxx
a        a2     p2xxxxx
a        a3     p1xxxxx
a        a4     p1xxxxx
b        b1     p1xxxxx
b        b2     p2xxxxx
b        b3     p3xxxxx
b        b4     p1xxxxx
b        b5     p2xxxxx
b        b6     p1xxxxx
c        c1     p3xxxxx
c        c2     p3xxxxx
c        c3     p2xxxxx
c        c5     p2xxxxx
c        c6     p3xxxxx
```

My aim is to get the count of a particular product "p1" where it's being placed and at which shelf and how much is qty of a "p1" product.
Then I calculate the total/ sum of "p1" product in a particular shop.

Below are the code for used in powerbi dax. I've created specific column for count and sum of the data.

```
count = if(
    CALCULATE(
        countrows(Table1),
        SEARCH("*p1*",Table1[product],,0))=blank(),
        0,
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(Table1),
            SEARCH("*p1*",Table1[product],,0)
            )
)
```

and

```
sum = CALCULATE(sum(Table1[count]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[shop]))
```

Below is the error while I published the sum formula in powerbi dax. Mostly this error appears on larger volume dataset.

> A circular dependency was detected. Table1[count],Table1[Sum],
> Table1[count].

My expected output (screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Please post your sample data as text.

Comment: @David: added sample dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're approaching it this way but try these two calculations:

```
count = 
    CALCULATE(
        countrows(Table1), ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[shop], Table1[product], Table1[shelf]),
        SEARCH("*p1*",Table1[product],,0)<>blank())
    +0


sum = CALCULATE(sum(Table1[count]),ALLEXCEPT(Table1,Table1[shop]))
```

[image]

Comment: The circular dependencies error is gone. The count query works fine. but the sum query counts all the rows in a particular shop. for  example shop "a" has 4 products in  which they have multiple products of p1, the sum query shows all 4 products  qty in shop "a'. It happens to a large volume of dataset.

Comment: The data which I've shared is masked and it's requirement of client.

Comment: The answer works with your sample data and I believe the question is answered as it was posed. If you have other issues I suggest asking a different question as this seems solved.